# How do you give someone n options from A or B?

Tags: questions, lists, and-or

I have a list A and a list B, and I want someone to be able to choose n from the cumulative list formed by combining A and B. However, my initial attempts were subpar at best:

> You get n of your choice from list A and list B

I read this as you get n from A *and* n from B

> You get n of your choice from list A or list B

I read this as you decide *either* A or B, and then choose n from it.

How do you correctly word my request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

> Pick N from **any** of A or B.
>
> Make N selections from **any** of A or B.

You need the word *any* in there.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all doubt at the risk of being slightly redundant, you can say "select a *total* of n from *among* A and B.

Comment: @tchrist (Yes, among, since both A and B represent many things) ...  ;)